# Dynamics AX V4 compatibility

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to install and execute Dynamics AX V4 on server 2012 ?

My database is a SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on a server 2008 R2, my AOS is running on Server 2008 R2.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation (which I can hardly find anymore), it needs `Server 2003`, but installing an AOS is pretty easy, you could try it and see how it behaves.

Microsoft often has a move-forward attitude. So when Server 2012 (`Sept 2012`) came out, `AX 2012` was already out (`Sept 2011`), so it's unlikely they went back 2 versions for compatibility testing.

If you're on `4.0` you should consider upgrading though as it reached its end of life `10/11/2016`. See end of life here: [Dynamics AX V4 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582708/dynamics-ax-v4-compatibility)